# Visible Edge between N-Gons + Shade Smooth

Tags: modeling

n-gons + smooth shading produces visible Edges. What would be best practice to solve this while keeping the n-gons in Blender 2.82a. Cant remember having this problem in 2.79.

the vertices are all on the same hight.
with shade flat there isnt an edge visible.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried edge split? Ultimately all faces are broken down into tris for smooth shading.

Comment: maybe try to go in the Properties panel > Object Data > Normals and enable Auto-Smooth, play with Angle value?

Comment: thanks J_M and moonboots unfortunately both methods dont work because they both are meant to exclude all angles above their value. This thing happens around 7degree wich means to whole mesh would be flat just to fix this issue.